# OSError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wntr/epanet/Darwin/libepanet22_win32.dylib, 6): image not found

Tags: python, django

I updated billiard,celery,kombu,amqp : nothing worked, Please help me resolve this. I am trying to use https://wntr.readthedocs.io/

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-6ccee6a8a438> in <module>
      1 # Simulate hydraulics
      2 sim = wntr.sim.EpanetSimulator(wn)
----> 3 results = sim.run_sim()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wntr/sim/epanet.py in run_sim(self, file_prefix, save_hyd, use_hyd, hydfile, version)
     94         inpfile = file_prefix + '.inp'
     95         self._wn.write_inpfile(inpfile, units=self._wn.options.hydraulic.inpfile_units, version=version)
---> 96         enData = wntr.epanet.toolkit.ENepanet(version=version)
     97         rptfile = file_prefix + '.rpt'
     98         outfile = file_prefix + '.bin'

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wntr/epanet/toolkit.py in __init__(self, inpfile, rptfile, binfile, version)
    155             except Exception as E1:
    156                 if lib == libnames[-1]:
--> 157                     raise E1
    158                 pass
    159         return

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wntr/epanet/toolkit.py in __init__(self, inpfile, rptfile, binfile, version)
    148                 elif sys.platform in ['darwin']:
    149                     libepanet = resource_filename(epanet_toolkit,'Darwin/lib%s.dylib' % lib)
--> 150                     self.ENlib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libepanet)
    151                 else:
    152                     libepanet = resource_filename(epanet_toolkit,'Linux/lib%s.so' % lib)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    457 
    458     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 459         return self._dlltype(name)
    460 
    461 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    379 
    380         if handle is None:
--> 381             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    382         else:
    383             self._handle = handle

OSError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wntr/epanet/Darwin/libepanet22_win32.dylib, 6): image not found
```

Everything worked earlier. I am using MacOS Sierra 10.13.6

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue both with OWA-epanet and epanet-toolkit python libraries.

I solved this by putting the Epanet .dylib file in ~/lib/

This way MacOS is able to find it without messing with the standard dylibs path.

The other option is to place it within your virtual environment folder